# How to Display Image in the Image Control using FileUpload?

Tags: asp.net

I just call this function on a button click.
 I also want to know in which event of FileUpload I can call this function.

```
 Function upload() As Boolean
        Dim img As FileUpload = CType(imgUpload, FileUpload)
        imgByte = Nothing
        If img.HasFile AndAlso Not img.PostedFile Is Nothing Then
            Dim File As HttpPostedFile = imgUpload.PostedFile
            imgByte = New Byte(File.ContentLength - 1) {}
            File.InputStream.Read(imgByte, 0, File.ContentLength)
        End If
        Dim strImagePath As String = imgUpload.FileName
        imgUpload.PostedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("..\Temporary\" + strImagePath))
        imgLogo.ImageUrl = Server.MapPath("..\Temporary\" + strImagePath)
        imgLogo.DataBind()
    End Function
```

---

Even after setting the url, image is not showing.I am sure that image file is created on the server and the path specified is right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use your relative path, as needed to your image to be read from your browser:

```
imgLogo.ImageUrl = "../Temporary/" + strImagePath
```

Comment: Farias , Which event of FileUpload I can use for this purpose.

Comment: Since your upload procedure is ok, just update in your code above

Comment: It's cleared . Thank you. I just added new button for uploading and showing that image.The FileUpload has only few events. All are firing on load and unload page.its not useful.unless i can reduce one upload button in my page.

Answer (score 1):

`imgLogo.ImageUrl = Server.MapPath("..\Temporary\" + strImagePath)`

This statement will be rendered as something similar to the following:

```
<img src="c:\...\sitelocationparent\Temporary\imagename.jpg" />
```

This is not the way the application should be server the image file.

It should be something like this (depending on where is the path of the aspx file):

```
imgLogo.ImageUrl = "../Temporary/" & imgUpload.FileName
```

Answer (score 0):

please try this:

```
imgUpload.PostedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/Temporary/") + strImagePath))

imgLogo.ImageUrl=("~/Temporary/+ strImagePath)
```

It's work!

Comment: Why should the OP "try this"? A **good answer** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done that way, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO that may find this question and be reading your answer.